# Differentiation : derivative of product of 2 polynomial

Tags: calculus

\begin{align}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac {dv}{dx}u+\frac {du}{dx}v \end{align}
So in order to understand the derivatives of the formula above, I saw this

\begin{align}&y=(2x+1)(x+1) \\ &u=(2x+1),\ v=(x+1) \\
&y=uv\end{align}
but then somehow this happened

\begin{align}y+\delta y=(u+\delta u)(v+\delta v)\end{align}

and I don't understand how those deltas are related to each other, and how do they even cancel each other out?

Explanation please ._.? thanks

**EDIT:** I know how it becomes the formula from there on, but what I wanted to know is how the delta(y), delta(u), (v) can just pop out in the last equation, I don't understand, and how would they cancel each other out?

Comment: The given formula doesn't appear to make sense. Presumably you want the product rule
$$\frac{d}{dx}(uv) = \frac{du}{dx} v + u \frac{dv}{dx},$$ which applies to all differentiable functions $u, v$, and not just polynomials.

Comment: @Travis O.O sorry typo it is dy/dx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

although symbols like $\delta x$ do appear the same as $\delta$ multiplied by $x$, this appearance is misleading. the symbol $\delta$ has a special interpretation in elementary differential calculus. the symbol $u+h$ is just a sum. the symbol $u+\delta u$ is a sum in which the second term is intended to be (in some suitable sense) *small* compared with the first.

the syntactic clumsiness of this traditional notation may be what has mislead you! but you probably are well aware that we cannot write:
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y}{x}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Expand the right-hand side and subtract $y=uv$:
$$
\delta y = uv + u \,\delta v + v \,\delta u + (\delta u)(\delta v) - uv
= u \,\delta v + v \,\delta u + (\delta u)(\delta v)
$$
Divide by $\delta x$:
$$
\frac{\delta y}{\delta x} = u \frac{\delta v}{\delta x} + v \frac{\delta u}{\delta x} + \delta u \frac{\delta v}{\delta x}
$$
Now let $\delta x \to 0$.  If $u$ and $v$ are differentiable, then $\delta u \to 0$, $\frac{\delta u}{\delta x}\to\frac{du}{dx}$, and $\frac{\delta v}{\delta x} \to \frac{dv}{dx}$.  Hence
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = v \frac{du}{dx}+u \frac{dv}{dx}
$$